# What procedure is called if "someVariable['key'] = value" is executed

Tags: python, c-api

I´m trying to write a python interface with C-API for my application.
I can create a module and add procedures and import them in the python context. Then I can run python scripts to access the module and procedures.

I would like to use a key to access data like:
module.someVar['key'] = value
or 
print(module.someVar['key'])

Then I would like to use the key and the data in a proceure in the C-Code.
What procedure is called in the pyTypeObject?

Edit: SomeVar is a variable of a type which it seems like I have to create. 
And yes, after the comments, it is a dict-like object. 
It seems that the first answer points me right point, I am currently testing it.

Comment: What is `someVar`? Is its type a type you wrote?

Comment: that sounds like a dict object

Comment: So you want to define a dictionary like object in an extension module? If that is what you want please edit your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

[Container types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types)

I think you are looking for `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`

eg:

```
class C:
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print(f"a['{item}'] called")

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        print(f"a['{item}'] = {value} called")

a = A()
a["get"]
>> a['get'] called
a["set"] = 0
>> a['set'] = 0 called
```